# Office 2013 offline installer

Tags: office-2013-preview

Is there any way to download the new office 2013 as a `.iso` file or some other format of offline installer? Also how much is the size of the downloadable files?

Comment: BEWARE. The installer will give you a option to keep your Outlook 2010, but will uninstall it regardless. This sucks

Answer (score 4):

The MSDN Subscription Downloads for Office 2013 (the couple I've checked anyway) are `.exe`, but given their size (~600–700MB) compared to Office 2010 (2525MB) there must be some form of dynamic download going on.

This is a first open preview, at this stage it is common for not all installation options to be available (equally only "Professional Plus" edition is available).