# How to download multiple IMG files of Office 2013?

Tags: download, iso-image, microsoft-office-2013

I have just bought Office 2013 Home and Business (only a key card), so I logged in at https://office.microsoft.com/de-de/MyAccount.aspx and downloaded an ISO image. It seems that the ISO is generated just for me, because it displays a license key.

It seems that there is no way of adding another license key to my office account. However, I'd not like to set up a bunch of LiveIDs just to download several copies of Office. Actually I hope I'd need to download it only once.

If I downloaded a CD image (.img) of Office 2013, can I use this image to install several copies of Office 2013 on different PCs with different license keys? If not, how would I obtain different CD images for each license key?

Not applicable answers on Superuser:

- [This answer](https://superuser.com/questions/449923/office-2013-offline-installer) seems to about professional preview version.
- [This answer](https://superuser.com/questions/580295/where-to-download-the-official-office-2013-to-use-with-a-pkc) is the one I already followed to download my first ISO.

Comment: You still need multiple licenses but you only have one. You purchase additional copies the same way you purchased the first one. There is a way to change the license key before launch office do that

Comment: @Ramhound: I have several key cards, but I could only activate one of them online.

Comment: What happens when you got to the page where you input the license after you attached one? You might open a support ticket with Microsoft